# How to pass username into function inside a form in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a form which has a variable that calls a function to get a list of names. I need to pass the current logged in user as a dynamic parameter variable into this function.

I have spent about 2 days on this trying to work any and every solution I can. Cannot find anything that works. I have tried to initialize a request object but cannot get that to work.

```
class ManagerForm(forms.Form):
    names = get_employee_names(<<dynamic username goes here>>)
    manager = forms.ChoiceField(choices=names, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

The expected result is to pass the username as a string into the function as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms by itself doesn't have access to `request` object and therefore can't identify which user is currently logged. Your view should pass current user username instead:

views.py:

```py
def index(request):
    # ...
    form = ManagerForm(request.POST or None, current_user_username=request.user.username)
    # ...
```

forms.py:

```
def get_employee_names(username):
    # assuming it constructs correct choices tuples, like:
    # choices = ((username, username), ('noname', 'noname'))
    return choices

class ManagerForm(forms.Form):
    manager = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[], widget=forms.RadioSelect)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        username = kwargs.pop('current_user_username')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['manager'].choices = get_employee_names(username)
```

[This is description of what django expect `choices` to be](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField.choices).

Comment: `names = get_employee_names(self.username)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

Comment: Order in code doesn't really matter. Try this one - we call `get_employee_names` in init instead, since there we should have called it in first place.

Comment: Same thing. `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`. In `choices=self.names`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, just woke up - here's 100% correct one

Comment: You don't know how long I worked on that and was so close at points. Only to have not realized that `choices` needed to be an empty list and `get_employee_names` passed in during __init__. The one thing I don't fully understand is how *args and **kwargs work but I will go watch some videos on that right away.

I am so extremely happy right now. Thank you very much! Is there a way to DM on here? I would like to see if I can pay you for help directly if I get stuck in spots.