# How to add field to form securely hidden

Tags: django, forms

I have a form that when submitted, it saves some data and one of these fields is a foreign key for user id. I want to pass this request.user.id value without it showing in the HTML code (I dont want people to change it in from the inspect because of security reasons).

This is the HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="container-fluid my-3">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        {% for field in form %}
        <div class="{% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %} col-2 {% else %} col-1 {% endif %}">
            {{ field }}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <div class="col-1">
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" display="inline" id='test'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the model:

```
class SaleEntry(models.Model):
date = models.DateField()
ebay_price = models.FloatField()
amazon_price = models.FloatField()
ebay_tax = models.FloatField()
paypal_tax = models.FloatField()
tm_fee = models.FloatField(default=0.3)
promoted = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
profit = models.FloatField()
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is the form:

```
class SaleEntryForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = SaleEntry
    fields = [
        'date',
        'ebay_price',
        'amazon_price',
        'ebay_tax',
        'paypal_tax',
        'tm_fee',
        'promoted',
        'profit'
    ]
    widgets = {
        'date': DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'ebay_price': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'eBay Price', 'id':'f_ebay_price', 'onchange': 'calc_profit()'}),
        'amazon_price': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Amazon Price', 'id':'f_amazon_price', 'onchange': 'calc_profit()'}),
        'ebay_tax': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control col-1', 'placeholder': 'eBay Tax', 'id':'f_ebay_tax', 'onchange': 'calc_profit()'}),
        'paypal_tax': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control col-1', 'placeholder': 'Paypal Tax', 'id':'f_paypal_tax', 'onchange': 'calc_profit()'}),
        'tm_fee': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control col-1', 'placeholder': 'TM Fee', 'id':'f_tm_fee', 'onchange': 'calc_profit()'}),
        'promoted': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control col-1', 'placeholder': 'Promoted', 'id':'f_promoted', 'onchange': 'calc_profit()'}),
        'profit': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Profit', 'readonly':'true', 'id':'f_profit'}),
    }
```

I can't save the form like this because I need to pass user_id.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current user directly from the views by getting using `request.user`

This can be passed directly into your forms.py using `'__init__'` in your form.

You can find more info here:
[How to pass username into function inside a form in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56248491/how-to-pass-username-into-function-inside-a-form-in-django)

Comment: I have already tried this method but it's raising KeyError when I'm choosing the key from kwargs and I can't figure out why.